# Jenkins: 'Docker not found' when run docker commands inside shell scripts

Tags: docker, jenkins

I need to be able to run docker command inside Jenkins pipeline. Although docker image of nodejs is pulled successfully in agent declarative, I cannot run any sh 'docker...' commands.

This is the Jenkinsfile which I use

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'node:lts-buster-slim'
            args '-p 8080:8080'
        }
    }
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Package') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def serverImage = docker.build('server-image')
                    serverImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the console output when I run

```
Started by user admin
Replayed #98
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/caches/git-636b462c19680f6faec2ce801ff0f9d4/.git # timeout=10
Setting origin to git@github.com:SonatBI/sonat-bi-be.git
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:SonatBI/sonat-bi-be.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Verifying host key using known hosts file
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/ci-cd
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-app-connector-level
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-app-connector-level-2
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-login
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-migration
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-notify-app-creation-and-update
Seen branch in repository origin/feature-service-account-authentication
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/test_git_action
Seen branch in repository origin/main
Seen branch in repository origin/test
Seen 11 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 3fa61d8834ff8833fb6932e6e55e919f14c6bd97
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential 012b2d70-1805-4b2d-a78a-cae178d81fac
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:SonatBI/sonat-bi-be.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:SonatBI/sonat-bi-be.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Verifying host key using known hosts file
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- git@github.com:SonatBI/sonat-bi-be.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3fa61d8834ff8833fb6932e6e55e919f14c6bd97 (ci-cd)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3fa61d8834ff8833fb6932e6e55e919f14c6bd97 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 3fa61d8834ff8833fb6932e6e55e919f14c6bd97 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:lts-buster-slim

Error: No such object: node:lts-buster-slim
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull node:lts-buster-slim
lts-buster-slim: Pulling from library/node
29cd48154c03: Pulling fs layer
6adc86b2ad66: Pulling fs layer
d1e2224c53ff: Pulling fs layer
efd2986195d0: Pulling fs layer
9cfcb540ec38: Pulling fs layer
efd2986195d0: Waiting
9cfcb540ec38: Waiting
6adc86b2ad66: Verifying Checksum
6adc86b2ad66: Download complete
efd2986195d0: Verifying Checksum
efd2986195d0: Download complete
29cd48154c03: Verifying Checksum
29cd48154c03: Download complete
9cfcb540ec38: Verifying Checksum
9cfcb540ec38: Download complete
d1e2224c53ff: Verifying Checksum
d1e2224c53ff: Download complete
29cd48154c03: Pull complete
6adc86b2ad66: Pull complete
d1e2224c53ff: Pull complete
efd2986195d0: Pull complete
9cfcb540ec38: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7c7394934f77f71deaf07b4893442c2f33927dfeeea1b7aad34dc23fc8f5bad0
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:lts-buster-slim
docker.io/library/node:lts-buster-slim
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container c9dde99b3a96e1dbffd136a20ac29003c8e806ce37e2f306c68252797500b9ff
but /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2 could not be found among []
but /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2@tmp could not be found among []
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2 -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:lts-buster-slim cat
$ docker top 9c570b68cdf99b579a8cf142ecd22e89d0ecf12f7b75213253295ed85ed3fd5a -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Package)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] sh
+ cd ../..
+ ls
workspace
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker version
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2@tmp/durable-b2359c6a/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonat-be-pipeline_ci-cd_2@tmp/durable-b2359c6a/script.sh: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 9c570b68cdf99b579a8cf142ecd22e89d0ecf12f7b75213253295ed85ed3fd5a
$ docker rm -f --volumes 9c570b68cdf99b579a8cf142ecd22e89d0ecf12f7b75213253295ed85ed3fd5a
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Beside, this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
networks:
  docker:

volumes:
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-docker-certs:

services:

  jenkins:
    image: myjenkins-blueocean:2.375.3-1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 50000:50000
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro
      - $HOME:/home
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376
      - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
      - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--httpPort=8081"

  dind:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      docker:
        aliases:
          - docker
    ports:
      - 2376:2376
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client
      - $HOME:/home
    environment:
      - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
```

I appreciate any helps or suggestions. Thank you.

And I notice only workspace folder is mounted from jenkins-data volume, but the volume actually contains lots of other folders; which also has 'job' folder I need to run some additional tools.

Comment: At which point are you trying to run `sh docker` commands? It would be helpful to get an overview of your architecture. Are you running Jenkins as a Docker image which in turn runs a Docker in Docker container which is used as the agent for you pipeline?

Comment: sorry I posted the wrong Jenkinsfile. The script block should be replaced by 'sh docker' command. I will edit post later.